# Calculate the mean of amino acids sequences biopython

Tags: python, sequence, biopython, dna-sequence

I have this code for calculating the length of sequences in fasta format using BioPython. I got the lenghts.

`NP_418305.1`

`349`

`NP_418306.1`

`469`

`NP_418308.1`

`236`

However, now I'd like to calcule the mean of the whole sequences, just like an intereting fact that I can add to my research. Will be great to get some advices.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
```

`record_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse("aminoacids.txt", "fasta"))`

`for key in record_dict.items():`

`print(key[0],"\n ",len(key[1].seq))`

Comment: We'd have to understand how to meaningfully add sub-sequences into a larger sequence.  Can you explain how you plan to do it?  Once you do the calculation of length appears to be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the mean of total length by summing each length of every sequence and dividing by the total of sequences.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).